# Transiesta convergence

Tags: siesta

I'm trying to find the I-Vg curve of a specefic system using transiesta implementation of gate. The problem that I encountered is the non-convergence of calculation even though they get below the dHmax and dDmax threshold:

```
ts-scf:  376   -24915.567447   -24915.567447   -24915.567447  0.000000 -5.273126  0.000000
ts-err-D: ij(  615,   615), M = 0.82931   , ew = -.43081E-3, em = 0.84114E-3. avg_em = 0.19371E-06
ts-err-E: ij( 1031,  1083), M = -.45300   , ew = -.52388E-5, em = 0.99605E-5. avg_em = -.69752E-09
```

Answer (score 0):

TranSiesta 4.1.5 defaults to requiring the following 3 quantities to be converged:

- `dHmax` Hamiltonian convergence
- `dDmax` Density matrix convergence
- `dq` charge convergence

The last one `dq`, can be quite difficult to achieve, and it requires some "feeling" for the system.
Generally `dq` convergence can be achieved by extending the system so that it the scattering region is better screened off.

From what you show, we can't see what the actual cause is:

1. We don't know what your options are
2. We can't see `dq` data